# need to remove empty value in array

Tags: php, arrays

Hi i need help in array creating

i have set of the records in array in that i have to replace empty array with "&nbsp";

condition if all the array values are empty need to remove row from that array
if one or two values are empty in row need to replace with "&nbsp";

i have tried remove empty values, but while inserting the record it throw error coz all column will not match the insert condition

i,e below i have placed sample array value in that i to remove first row coz all the values are empty, and in 2 row i have replace empty value to "&nbsp";

```
Array
(
[0] => 
[1] => 
[2] => 
[3] => 
[4] => 
[5] => 
)
Array
(
[0] => abcd@abcd.com
[1] => abcd@abcd.com
[2] => 
[3] => abcd@abcd.com
[4] => abcd@abcd.com
[5] => abcd@abcd.com
)
foreach ($rows as $r) {
$SweepedArray = array_values(array_filter($r));
if (!empty($SweepedArray) && $SweepedArray != "") {
$value[] = implode(',', $r);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
foreach ($rows as &$r) {
    if (empty($r)) {
        $r = "";
    }
}
```